# Will a wget process continue to run after administrator is logged out?

Tags: process, wget, windows-server-2008-r2

I logged into a Windows 2008 server via remote desktop as Administrator and started a wget process which will take 24 hours to download 29 files.

If someone happens to log in during that time and "logs the administrator out" so that they can log in, will the wget process be killed or continue to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they force a logout on the Administrator the session will be killed. If they log into that same session, it will continue running.

To make this easier we tend to use the `admin` switch to log in for long running operations, to ensure that the session doesn't get accidentally killed by forcing a logoff.

The best way to do this is to put the command in a batch file and do a once off task scheduler task for it, which will ensure it runs irrelevant of who is logged in or not.